# .htaccess Rewriting Tomcat Server

Tags: .htaccess, tomcat, url-rewriting, railo

I am writing a website using Railo. My code is to be deployed on a Railo Server running on Tomcat, overlayed on a regular Apache+PHP server.

I need to send all requests to `http://subdomain.myserver.co.uk/` and its child files to the directory `/public_html/railo/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/subdomain/` directory.

I defined a subdomain in cPanel, with the document root as `/public_html/railo/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/subdomain/`, but still requests to `http://subdomain.myserver.co.uk/` display files in `/public_html/railo/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/`. I can view my files if I request `http://subdomain.myserver.co.uk/subdomain/`

I've been fiddling with the .htaccess files for quite some time now, but I'm stuck

Is there any way I can do what I'm trying to achieve, or am I resigned to get those pages using `http://subdomain.myserver.co.uk/subdomain/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cherouvim's answer didn't work for me. Eventually I ended up putting my entire application in the `ROOT` directory

Answer (score 3):

The Railo documentation on adding a site to a Railo/Tomcat/Apache/Linux install is here:

http://wiki.getrailo.org/wiki/Installation:InstallerDocumentation:LinAddingSites

I would also personally recommend *against* putting your site files in ROOT/sitedir/ because the ROOT directory is already configured for localhost, and making a subdirectory into another site will cause overlapping host configs in the WEB-INF directories.

Instead, just use whatever the default is for your control panel, and update your Tomcat server.xml file to point to the directory that your control panel naturally puts sites in. This will make your Railo site and your control panel work very smoothly together.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So I put it in `ROOT`, is that ok? how (in what way) do I modify the server.xml if I want to do what you suggested?

Comment: Put your site files wherever you normally do in cPanel. I believe cPanel creates a home directory for your site whenver you create a new site using it, correct? Just place your CFM files in that same directory along with your images, CSS, etc.

Comment: Check the link I posted above for HOW to modify the server.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your tomcat application to serve at `example.com` and not at `example.com/application` then you need to deploy your application at `/ROOT` and not at `/application`. This will make it the "default web application" so it'll be able to serve directly from `example.com`.

Have a look at: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html

Comment: Is there no way I can have it rewritten to example.com/application?

Comment: Yes, you could rewrite using mod_rewrite, but why do that? Don't you have access to how the tomcat application is being deployed?

Comment: I've never done this server admin stuff before, but the client does not want the app in the root. He wants it in `ROOT/subdir` and then he wants to access it using `http://subdir.domain.co.uk`

Comment: What do you mean by "does not want the app in the root"? Does this regard where the physical files of the app exist on the server?

Comment: yeah. The server has a directory `/public_html/railo/tomcat/webapps/ROOT`. The client wants me to put my application in `/public_html/railo/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/enterprise`. And then, he wants users to access the app using `http://enterprise.domain.co.uk`. So I added a subdomain in cPanel such that `http://enterprise.domain.co.uk` has the document root of `/public_html/railo/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/enterprise`. However, going to `http://enterprise.domain.co.uk` gives me the index.cfm page in `/public_html/railo/tomcat/webapps/ROOT` even though I specified the document root for the subdomain to be

Comment: contd...  `/public_html/railo/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/enterprise`

Comment: So I thought possibly I could rewrite the url from `http://enterprise.domain.co.uk` to actually execute the page at `http://enterprise.domain.co.uk/enterprise/` or even `http://www.domain.co.uk/enterprise/` if necessary

Comment: If you put it in `webapps/ROOT/enterprise` it will not work as a tomcat application, but rather as a bunch of files under the default (ROOT) application. You can either place the app under `webapps/ROOT` or under `webapps/enterprise` etc.

Comment: ah, ok Thanks...lemme try it out

Comment: so do I add a subdomain to the server with a document root at `/railo/tomcat/webapps/enterprise` or what?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4902/discussion-between-pranav-hosangadi-and-cherouvim)